# How to define a run-length sequence with additional column condition

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

This is a follow up to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52344379/define-sequences-based-on-a-variable-run-with-additional-condition-from-another).  Like there, I need to define a run-length type id of group column (ignoring `NA`), with additional column `seq_break` indicating that a sequence should be ended while `seq_break = TRUE`. However, solution provided in that topic starts a new sequence in a row where `seq_break = TRUE`, while in fact it should be included as a last event of previous sequence. Example data is attached below. The difference can be observed in row `46` - previous solution would start the sequence element `13` here, while I need it to be included in sequence `12`.

```
df <- structure(list(group = c(NA, NA, "home", "home", "home", "home", 
"home", "home", "away", NA, NA, "home", "home", "home", NA, NA, 
NA, "home", "away", "away", NA, "away", "away", "away", "home", 
"away", "away", "away", NA, "home", "home", NA, NA, "away", NA, 
NA, "home", NA, NA, "home", "home", "home", "home", "home", "home", 
"home", "away", "away", NA, NA), seq_break = c(FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE), expected_output = c(NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, NA, NA, 
3, 3, 3, NA, NA, NA, 4, 5, 5, NA, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, NA, 9, 
9, NA, NA, 10, NA, NA, 11, NA, NA, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
13, 13, NA, NA)), .Names = c("group", "seq_break", "expected_output"
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L))
```

Any ideas how to accomplish that with `tidyverse`? I can't figure out how `cumsum` could be replaced here...

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Sorry to clarify: you want to change to a new id when either `group` changes or `seq_break` is TRUE?

Comment: @www, I added a column with expected output.

Comment: @CalumYou, actually, when `group` changes or after `seq_break = TRUE`. I added a little explanation based on example and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a new column to call `seq_break2` and add to the pipeline as follows. This creates the same result as your expected output.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

df2 <- df %>% 
  select(-expected_output) %>%
  rowid_to_column() 

df3 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(seq_break2 = ifelse(seq_break & !is.na(group), FALSE, seq_break)) %>%
  mutate(ID = rleid(group, seq_break2)) %>%
  group_by(group, seq_break2, ID) %>%
  filter(!(is.na(group) & seq_break2 & row_number() > 1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(ID2 = cumsum(seq_break2)) %>%
  drop_na(group) %>%
  mutate(expected_output = rleid(group, ID2)) %>%
  select(rowid, expected_output) %>%
  left_join(df2, ., by = "rowid") %>%
  select(-rowid)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using rleid and shift from data.table...

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

# make groups
df[, v := rleid(group, shift(cumsum(seq_break)))]

# drop if group is NA
df[is.na(group), v := NA]

# renumber the others
df[!is.na(group), v := .GRP, by=v]

# check
stopifnot( df[, all.equal(v, expected_output)] )
```

The `seq_break` column is actually irrelevant in the example, so I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly:

```
df[, v2 := rleid(group)][is.na(group), v2 := NA][!is.na(group), v2 := .GRP, by=v2]

# check
stopifnot( df[, all.equal(v2, expected_output)] )
```

---

Since OP want's a 'verse answer, here's one translation (still using rleid):

```
library(dplyr)
res = df  %>% mutate(
  v2 = data.table::rleid(group) %>% replace(is.na(group), NA),
  v2 = match(v2, na.omit(unique(v2)))
) 

# check
stopifnot( with(res, all.equal(v2, expected_output)) )
```